# Access text of Multiline TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview

I want to access text of particular line in a multi-line TextView. Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetch the Layout ([android.text.Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html)) of the TextView by calling mTextView.getLayout(); There you can for instance use the getLineStart or getLineEnd methods to get the offset of the text. That combined with getText and used using normal String operations should probably be enough for u!

Comment: dear i try this , but it generates error; layout l = txt1.getlayout(); then i use l.getlinestart() but it generates error what soukd i do for taht

Comment: What error does it generate? I guess you need to wait for calling this until the TextView has been layouted

Answer (score 0):

By default, text view is multi line. Set the text with new line characters for ex. "First line \nSecond line".

Another option is listed here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610280/how-to-get-multi-line-text-on-a-button-in-android